# Haskell Round Number

Tags: haskell, decimal, rounding

I have a haskell function which looks like that:

```
x 1 = 1 :: Double
x n = ((n-1)/3 + 1/(n-1)) * ((x (n-1))^2) - (n-1)^3/3 + 1 :: Double
```

Don't think about the formula, it should just add one, so x 2 = 2; x 3 = 3 and so on.
But the results in Haskell are:

```
*Main> x 2
2.0
*Main> x 3
2.9999999999999996
*Main> x 4
3.9999999999999964
*Main>
```

Can someone tell me, what I need to add in line number two so it is round the number to 6 decimal digits?
I don't want to parse to int!

Thanks!

Comment: do you just want to have it printed up to the 6decimal point or do you want numbers with only 6 positions after the comma.

Comment: I want to use numbers rounded with 6 positions as x n. So no printing, it should be the internal number.

Answer (score 6):

You may used the [`Fixed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Fixed) type for arithmetic with a fixed precision after the decimal point. There is even [a type synonym for six decimal digits of precision](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Micro). For example, let's define:

```
x :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => a -> a
x 1 = 1
x n = ((n-1)/3 + 1/(n-1)) * ((x (n-1))^2) - (n-1)^3/3 + 1
```

Now we can try it in `ghci` with six digits of precision:

```
Data.Fixed> x <$> [1,2,3,4] :: [Micro]
[1.000000,2.000000,2.999998,3.999981]
```

Of course, using fewer digits of precision doesn't actually help! You can't fix rounding errors by using *less* precision, only more. So, why not go for full precision? Since you are only using operations that need `Fractional`, you can use `Rational` for exact arithmetic. In ghci:

```
> x <$> [1,2,3,4] :: [Rational]
[1 % 1,2 % 1,3 % 1,4 % 1]
```

Perfect! (Read `%` as division.)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not Haskell, it's the binary representation of floating point numbers. Any language will give you similar results.

Saying that you want to "round" to a certain number of decimal digits is tricky because the binary representation for many decimal values is not exact. `0.1` decimal, for instance, is `0.000110011001100110011...` recurring. For more about the details of floating point numbers and the headaches they can cause you should read *[What every computer scientist should know about floating point](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf)*.

To see why binary fractions cause problems, consider `1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3`.  Obviously that is equal to 1. But if you round to 3 decimal places you get `0.333 + 0.333 + 0.333 = 0.999`. Look familiar?

Now try evaluating `[0,0.1..1]`

You can get approximately what you want by multiplying by `1e6`, rounding to the nearest integer, and dividing by `1e6`. You say you don't want to "parse" to an Int, but it's the only way to do this. The reason I say that you only get approximately what you want is that obviously if your number rounds to `0.1` then you still only get an approximation instead of the exact value.

A function to round to 6 decimal places in Haskell would be

```
round6dp :: Double -> Double
round6dp x = fromIntegral (round $ x * 1e6) / 1e6

> round6dp pi
3.141593
```

Also, you might try importing `Data.Ratio` and replacing the type `Double` with `Rational` in your code. Rational numbers are expressed as a ratio between two integers, so you can represent 1/3 exactly. Haskell uses `%` as the ratio operator to distinguish it from normal division, so you can evaluate `1%3 / 3%2`.  If you do this then your code gives the right answer.

Comment: Yes sure you are right. But how do I solve the problem itself? The function which you see will return just the number itself. So x 5 = 5, x 53 = 53 and so on. Normally without those binary problems.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do. You asked to round the number to 6dp, so I gave you a function to do that. Try adding it to your source code and then calling it from within `x`.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw half of your answer. Seems like you edited later. Thank you for your answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

First off, that function will easily go wrong. You're recursing down a floating-point number; if you miss `1` it'll just continue decreasing, down to -∞ (or in fact, down to -9×10<sup>15</sup>, because from that point, decrementing by one won't actually change the float value anymore and it'll just loop on forever). So, it should actually be

```
x :: Double -> Double
x n
 | n>1        = ((n-1)/3 + 1/(n-1)) * ((x (n-1))^2) - (n-1)^3/3 + 1
 | otherwise  = 1
```

Next, if you're troubled by the deviations from the expected exact results... [welcome to the world of floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)! There are plenty of good uses for FP, but in none of them it should matter if there's a discrepancy at the 15th decimal. If this does matter for you, you should *not* use any floats, but make the signature

```
x :: Rational -> Rational
```

and immediately the results will be exact, though they'll appear in notation that looks a bit weird:

```
*Main> x <$> [1..3]
[1 % 1,2 % 1,3 % 1]
```

Now, all that said, there are ways to just *suppress the symptoms* of floating point. What you've asked for, “rounding a number internally”, can be achieved like thus:

```
quantize₁₀ :: Int -> Double -> Double
quantize₁₀ n x = fromIntegral (round $ x * η) / η
 where η = 10^n
```

then (with `x :: Double -> Double` again)

```
*Main> quantize₁₀ 6 . x <$> [1..3]
[1.0,2.0,3.0]
```

I would strongly recommend against this – again, if you find this kind of manipulation necessary, you probably shouldn't be using floating-point numbers at all.

A more reasonable thing would be to just have the *string output* rounded, without doing anything about the numbers themselves. The traditional way for this is C's `printf`, which also exists in Haskell:

```
*Main Text.Printf> printf "%.6f\n" $ x 3
3.000000
```

Comment: If you end up using `quantize` then you should consider if you actually want `round` vs `floor` or `ceiling` or another rounding method.  Notice `round` in Haskell is bankers rounding - it has nice properties in certain contexts but is sometimes unexpected.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson you almost certainly don't want `floor` or `ceiling` if this is at all a sensible floating-point application. OTOH, whether you use banker's rounding or round-to-zero for `.5` hits should make virtually no difference, because these values would turn up only neglectably seldom (in ℝ – which is what you should be modelling with the FP numbers – they're in fact a null set).

Answer (score 2):

As leftroundabout says, you should probably use `Rational` for your calculation to be exact.  Rounding after the fact will cause troubles.

However, you can use [Data.Number.BigFloat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.1/docs/Data-Number-BigFloat.html) from the `numbers` package, it provides decimal floating point with a configurable precision.  This answers your question of "how to round to 6 significant decimal figures", as long as you remain in a type precise enough (eg `Rational` or `BigFloat` with a same or higher precision).  Converting back to `Double` (for example) will just give you problems again.

It may be useful in some circumstances to do exact calculations with `Rational`, then convert to `Decimal6` only for rounding (and then back to `Rational` again).

Example code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Data.Number.BigFloat

type Prec6 = EpsDiv10 (EpsDiv10 (EpsDiv10 (EpsDiv10 (EpsDiv10 Eps1))))
type Decimal6 = BigFloat Prec6

decimal6 :: Decimal6 -> Decimal6
decimal6 = id

double :: Double -> Double
double = id

fixed = print . decimal6 . realToFrac

broken = print . double . realToFrac . decimal6 . realToFrac

examples :: [Double]
examples = [pi, exp pi, exp (exp pi), exp (negate (exp pi))]

x 1 = 1
x n = ((n-1)/3 + 1/(n-1)) * ((x (n-1))^2) - (n-1)^3/3 + 1

testx = print . x

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "fixed:"  >> mapM_ fixed examples
  putStrLn "broken:" >> mapM_ broken examples
  putStrLn "Rational:" >> mapM_ testx [1 .. 3 :: Rational]
  -- no Enum instance for BigFloat, so can't use [..] syntax at that type
  putStrLn "Decimal6:" >> mapM_ (testx . decimal6 . fromInteger) [1 .. 3]
```

Output:

```
fixed:
3.14159e0
2.31407e1
1.12169e10
8.91509e-11
broken:
3.1415929203539825
23.14070351758794
1.1216931216931217e10
8.915094339622642e-11
Rational:
1 % 1
2 % 1
3 % 1
Decimal6:
1.00000e0
2.00000e0
3.00000e0
```

Answer (score 0):

As already explained, your problem is the finite precision used to represent numbers in computers. For higher precision floating point numbers you might want to have a look at the package [Data.Scientific](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.5.2/docs/Data-Scientific.html)

Comment: note that Data.Scientific's Fractional instance diverges (crashes) when dividing yields repeating decimals - it's more for safe I/O of untrusted numbers